# Smallest value of $x^4+2x^2+y^4-2y^2+3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question asks:

Find the smallest value (for real $x$ and $y$) of: $$x^4+2x^2+y^4-2y^2+3$$

I don't think I understand this question, it is in a completing the square exercise and I don't really know where to start. I can factorise parts and mess around with it but it does not help at all. Any help with explaining the question would be appreciated.

Comment: The Maple command $$minimize(x^4+y^4+2*x^2-2*y^2+3, x = -infinity .. infinity, y = -infinity .. infinity, location) $$ produces $$2, \{[\{x = 0, y = -1\}, 2], [\{x = 0, y = 1\}, 2]\}. $$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We observe that $$f(x,y):=x^4+2x^2+y^4-2y^2+3=(x^2+1)^2+(y^2-1)^2+1.$$

The minimum of $f(x,y)$ therefore occurs when $|x^2+1|$ is minimized and when $|y^2-1|$ is minimized.

Comment: I understand how you got to that point, that was the first thing I tried. For a function say $f(x)$ all I have to do is find the value of $x$ which returns the smallest value, but for $f(x,y)$ I don't understand how you can minimise both $|x^2+1|$ and $|y^2-1|$.

Comment: Wait can't I just say $x = 1$ and $y = 1$ which gives the smallest value of $2$?

Comment: @Johnmgee You mean **$x=0$** and $y = \pm1$ giving the smallest value.

Answer (score 1):

$x^4+2x^2+y^4-2y^2+3 = (x^2+1)^2 - 1 + (y^2 -1)^2 - 1 + 3 = (x^2+1)^2 + (y^2 - 1)^2 +1$ which must be minimal when the terms $(x^2+1)^2$ and $(y^2 - 1)^2$ are minimal, you should be able to take it from here.